# ReactJS Testing a helper method using jest spyOn

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

So I have the following helper method -

```
import { FormFieldError, FormValidationRules } from "../../../types/form.type";

const isString = (value: any, fieldId: string, fieldName: string): FormFieldError | null => {
  // Check if field value is of type string
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    return {
      fieldId,
      message: `${fieldName} must be string.`
    };
  }

  return null;
}

const validateField = (value: any, rules: FormValidationRules[], fieldId: string, fieldName: string): FormFieldError | null => {
  let error: FormFieldError | null = null;

  // Let's go through each of the rules
  for (const rule of rules) {
    // Let's check against mandatory value
    if (error === null && rule === 'string') {
      error = isString(value, fieldId, fieldName);
    } else if (error !== null) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // Let's return the error
  return error;
}

export default validateField;
```

Now I want to write a test that tests if `isString` method is called using spyOn. If I do something like this -

```
import validateField from './FormValidationRules';

describe('Test if necessary functions are called', () => {
  it('Should call isString method with according parameters', () => {
    const isStringSpy = spyOn(validateField, 'isString');

    validateField(null, ['string'], 'name', 'Name');

    expect(isStringSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

It complains about `Argument of type "isString" is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`.

If I try to add the method isString within the function validateField, it still complains about the same issue.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that property being spied on doesn't exist which in *typed terms* is a `NonFunctionPropertyName` type.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v24.9.0/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L965-L984

This is a valid error because in `./FormValidationRules` module the default export is `validateField` function and `isString` is **module private**.

I'll leave testing to focus on the results of validating non-string values passed for fields validated against a `string` rule and treat `isString` as an implementation detail. *e.g.*

```
result = validateField(null, ['string'], 'name', 'Name');
expect(result).toEqual({
      'name',
      message: 'Name must be string.'
    })
```

Unless `isString` is to be exposed in `./FormValidationRules` and used directly in your application, you can export it in  module, then mock it accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, I have already written tests for such a case. Just wondering, if this is sufficient and we there is no point for checking if particularly isString method is called? Just wondering from the best practice point of view.

Comment: `isString` is an implementation detail here unless you intend for it to be used externally from where it's declared. You could export `isString` to unit test it if that's a probable use case.  One importing `validateField` expects for it to behave as intended and does care what private methods it uses. Also, since you mentioned having unit tests already stressing `isString` via `validateField`, any test checking whether it's invoked or not is likely redundant